# Spark query pushdown is not working as expected for join

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-glue

I am writing a Spark program to fetch data from Snowflake. The program contains 1 simple SQL(join 2 tables, having <50000 records) as below.

```
val TABB = spark.sql("SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM XYZ WHERE DATE(COL2) >= DATE(ADD_MONTHS((DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), -(DAY(CURRENT_DATE())-1))),-3)) ")

TABB.CreateOrReplaceTempView("TAB1")

val TABA = spark.sql("SELECT COL1, "ABC"||COL3 AS COL4 FROM PQR WHERE YEAR(COL3)=2010 ")

TABA.CreateOrReplaceTempView("TAB2")


VAL result = spark.sql("SELECT A.COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4 FROM TAB1 A LEFT JOIN TAB2 B ON A.COL1=B.COL1 ")

result.count
```

The issue is, when I run this program, the execution takes long time and below is the Spark physical plan which I captured -

[image]

When I run the query individualy(TABB and TABA), it is running very fast, you can see the second physical plan above for same. The complete query(join) also run quickly in Snowflake directly)

Comment: Also Note: I have other Spark(Glue) programs, which process millions of records with multiple joins runs directly within Snowflake(Query pushdown) in a faster manner. The physical plan for this is similar to the second plan in the above image.

Comment: Try persisting/caching both the datasets before joining.

Comment: my main question is why is this join not running in Snowflake(query pushdown)?